# Hive find last occurrence

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

My apologies if there is an answer somewhere else.

I have a string stored in a Hive field that can have 0 to n occurrences of '&' followed by text after each occurrence.

In Hive, I would like to find the final occurrence and grab all the text after that occurrence.

Using ...

```
split(field1,'[&]')[n]
```

... I can grab the nth occurence, but I cannot predict the final or count backwards.

I was able to get the following to work:

```
reverse(split(reverse(field1),'[&]')[0])
```

However, using three functions seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead.  I know that you can use regex in regexp_extract(), but I am confounded by regex.

Would regexp_extract() be faster and how would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

```
[^&]*$
```

Capture all chars that are not `&` until the end of the string `$`